# Web developement software that connects using TLS V1.0 not SSL3.0

Tags: ssl, web

My web host has made my server more secure and is now requiring connection via FTP over SSL/TLS but they will not accept SSL3.0, only TLS1.0 or higher.

This rules out Dreamweaver CS6, Komposer, Microsoft Web Expressions 4.0.

Filezilla works, so all is not lost, but it makes it a two program process (develop in Dreamweaver, cross to Filezilla to upload)

Does anyone know of a Windows 7 program that can connect via FTP using TLS v1.0 or higher instead of SSL3.0

Any suggestions greatly appreciated
Cheers, Al.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a program called CoffeeCup HTML Editor.

It connects using TLSv1.0

I'm sure there are others, but this is the first one I found that I got to work and I am using it now.